# Same Web Property ID is Tracked Twice - Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ssl, redirect, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

All,

I have recently run into an issue where my bounce rate on my website [www.x3tradesmen.com](https://www.x3tradesmen.com) dropped significantly (less than 10% and sometime even 0%). I have read multiple threads trying to solve the issue and have downloaded a chrome extension "Google Tag Assistant". The extension is telling me "Same web property ID is tracked twice."

I cannot find how or where the web id is being tracked twice because I only have the GA script installed one time within the Avada theme options. I do have Google tag manager connected as well, however, it has been connected for a while and I never noticed a drop after installing it.

The most recent changes that I have made to our website is:

- Installing SSL certificate and "Really Simple SSL" plugin so my website is now https://www.x3tradesmen.com instead of http://www.x3tradesmen.com
- I have an old website x3staffing.com that I recently 301 redirected to go to https://www.x3tradesmen.com via the .htaccess file (GA script was removed from this website just in case)
- Installed W3 Total Cache plugin for basic cacheing features

Can anyone assist me with solving this issue and how I can make sure that **web property id is only being fired once**??

Thanks in advance!

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ECkp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounce rate issue is occurring because the page view is being fired twice.

Bounce is calculated based on when a user has a pageview and then no other interactive actions. So Google Analytics is thinking user navigated to homepage and then navigated to homepage again. Thus user did not bounce.
*(Your Exit Rate should be a more accurate representation of bounce rate if you are looking for a temporary solution to get that data.)*

Looking at the network requests it appears that a pageview is being fired by the original Google Analytics script as well as by Tag Manager.

Perhaps something changed recently in your Tag Manager to add a GA tag?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I added Google Tag Manager on 02/02/2018 and my bounce rate did not start to go down until 02/21/2018 and I have not touched Google Tag Manager since adding it... I did notice that when I look at the Google Tag Assistant it shows that it is storing the cookie twice but if I am being honest I am not sure what I am looking at there... Around the time the bounce rate decreased I did add a new plugin "W3 Total Cache" to assist with the speed of our website so I am wondering if it is possibly a caching issue, however, I have no idea where to being fixing?

Comment: I added an image link to the original question post that you can see when the bounce rate begins to drop and the events correlated with it.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps one of the changes on the site re-enabled GA have you tried turning off GA tracking in Wordpress Theme?

Alternatively turning of GA tracking tag in GTM.

Comment: you were correct! I removed the GTM script temporarily from the website and I no longer get the error alert on Google Tag Assistant... However, I am super confused to why that would fire the GA web property twice... Here is the code I removed:

Comment: <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-SAMPLE');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

Answer (score 1):

After receiving detailed information from Codeseer, I was able to identify that I was tracking all of my pageviews with a Google Tag Manager tag. I also had the Google Analytics script installed on my website, therefore, the web property ID was firing twice. I never made any changes to my original GTM tag so I am not sure why it all of the sudden started tracking twice but ultimately the solution was to remove the Google Analytics script and only use Google Tag Manager to fire the GA script. Thanks for all the help!